# Xcode 9 Simulator side buttons

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta

What is the purpose of side buttons on Xcode 9 Simulator?
[image]

Comment: It just mirroring the button like on real device, you can click any of those , for example the button on top right is for locking/unlocking the device and other button are for volume up/down.

Answer (score 3):

From the Help Viewer of the Simulator

[image]

Does nobody use the Help at all ? ...

Comment: Well, using the help provided, i.e. the Release Notes for beta 3, I assume that those buttons did not work in previous beta releases. In the section "Resolved in Xcode 9 beta 3", it says "The bezel ringer switch and volume buttons now control the simulated device’s volume and mute status (32118310, 32117708, 32118558)", so I assume they did not work previously.